# Integrating the IBM Watson Personality Insights API

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I am building a Web App and want to integrate the IBM Watson Personality Insights API.
I am using PHP and would have to use Curl Library for the same

Below is the code which is mentioned in the IBM documentation for using Curl

```
curl -X POST --user {username}:{password}
--header "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
--header "Accept: application/json"
--data-binary @<filename>
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile"
```

How do I do this in PHP?

I am trying to do this but i am getting an empty response

```
$ch2 = curl_init("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile");
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Language: en';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en';

$simple_data = 'Some dummy data';
    curl_setopt_array( $ch2, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $simple_data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $request_headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'XXXX:YYYY',
    )
);
$response2 = curl_exec( $ch2 );
```

Comment: where's `--header "Accept: application/json"` in your request?

Comment: i tried adding $request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json'; but nothing changed @MathieuBorderé

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script, and then `var_dump(curl_error($ch2));` after `curl_exec` to see if there were any errors.  As it is now, you're not outputting anything so it may be working.  What's `var_dump($response2);` show?

Comment: It is giving error as 'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain' so I added a 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false' this in my code. Now it's not giving any error but the response contains '{"code":400,"sub_code":"S00016","error":"No version provided"}' @drew010

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practose to have a valid SSL Certificate in order to get results from API. 
Try Following steps

1. Go to Firefox and visit https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile
2. Login with your Watson PI credentials
3. Click on the lock on left most side of the URL Bar and click on more information.
4. Click on View Certificate -> Details
5. The first Item in the hierarchy is your CA Certificate for IBM Watson PI, Export it to your machine.
6. Then Just Use this 3 line of Code within your Curl Request

   ```
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO , getcwd() . "\Your Certificate Location");
   ```